# How to display a node page in ctools modal?

Tags: 7, nodes, chaos-tool-suite

Is there any way to display a node page in the ctools modal.

I have searched for a contrib module but did not find one.

I know the following code will display the content in ctools modal, but can't figure out how to use it for a node.

```
ctools_include('ajax');
ctools_include('modal');
$popup_content = 'some content;
$output = array();
$output[] = ctools_modal_command_display(t('Confirmation'), $popup_content);
print ajax_render($output);
drupal_exit();
```

As I have a view displaying nodes with read more link. When I click on the readmore, that node should display in ctools modal.

I know I can figure out a solution for this problem is to create a path like `article/%` and in the callback I will load the node and will use the above code to display the node content.

But I'm looking for a clean solution, where the readmore should link to `node/[nid]` in actual but with node alias. and the node page appears in ctools modal.

Comment: Not sure: is your question how to print the node in the modal or how to create the node/[nid] path that will invoke the modal?